# First char of string to upper case: what is more costly to the server? C#

Tags: c#, string, uppercase

I have two ways to get the first letter of a string to upper case, but I would like to know which one uses more server resources?
(MVC 5, C#)

```
string test1 = test.ToUpper()[0] + test.Substring(1);
```

or

```
string test1 = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(test.ToLower());
```

Comment: Why don't you use a `stopwatch` class and check by yourself. Also, you can go for a extension method.

Comment: Both are fine.  In comparison to other things your web application is probably doing (DB queries etc.) this is negligible.  But as Rahul said, why don't you just benchmark it?  It's easy to test how long it takes to perform this conversion, like 10000 times in a loop.  At least it gives you an idea how much stress it puts on the CPU.  Checking memory usage is trickier.

Comment: Please note that this two lines of code can result in pretty different strings due to `test.ToLower()` in a second one.

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your ExtensionMethods.cs

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string UppercaseFirstLetter(this string value)
    {
       //
       // Uppercase the first letter in the string this extension is called on.
       //
       if (value.Length > 0)
       {
           char[] array = value.ToCharArray();
           array[0] = char.ToUpper(array[0]);
           return new string(array);
       }
       return value;
    }
}
```

According to : http://www.dotnetperls.com/uppercase-first-letter it is faster than your first method because because it only allocates one new string in the return statement. The first approach allocates two strings: the Substring(1), and then a new string with string.Concat.

Comment: Only one thing wrong, you should set the other string to Lower. This would fail in these cases.

LoWer, loweR. The author asked that he needs the first letter to be in uppercase and by reading his code, its probably the only thing he wants.

So modify it to something like this

char firstChar = char.ToUpper(value[0]);
return firstChar + value.Substring(1);

Answer (score 2):

I made a dotnetfiddle which tests the performance of the two methods you mentioned, plus the one suggested by SatuDuaTiga.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/VyNjht

The method suggested by SatuDuaTiga seems to outperform the first method by a small margin, but using .ToTitleCase() in the CultureInfo namespace is by far the worst.

Average results of multiple runs:

- Method 1: 93673 ticks
- Method 2: 260491 ticks
- Method 3: 90649 ticks

You can disassemble the TextInfo class and view the source of the .ToTitleCase() method and you'll see it's doing a lot of stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Well I did a small benchmarking to check it out and there is no such observable difference present between the two approaches. You can use the below code to perform the same at your end. Try, running it multiple times as suggested by @ta.speot.is in below comment.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Benchmark();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void Benchmark()
    {
        string test = "rahul";
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        string test1 = test.ToUpper()[0] + test.Substring(1);
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks);

        watch.Restart();
        string test2 = 
             CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(test.ToLower());
        watch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedTicks);
    }
```

If you run it multiple times then it looks like first approach it bit faster than the second one. I tried it for 5 times and below goes the result

```
4
5

2
4

2
3

2
3
```

Comment: Did you run this multiple times? Because the first result could easily be caused by a context switch or two or paging or the JIT JIT'ing or the GC GC'ing... Try `ToTitleCase` first.

Comment: Yes, every time the difference is observable. Try once on your end (just wanted to confirm once)

Comment: Interesting... I ran this on my computer and consistently got about 80 ticks for the first test and 150 ticks for the second.

Comment: Nope, looks like @ta.speot.is is correct. There is no such observable difference present.

Comment: i'd tried to run the test 10k times and have seen first one is twice faster

Comment: @MadSorcerer, Yes and edited my answer to include that observation but it's not twice faster though; can't claim that.